# Minecraft 1.8.9 shield recipe not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried both the new and the older shield recipe and neither one is working. I have tried different types ofv wood. Any suggestions?

Comment: if someone has answered your question and the answer helps you, which as I can see, both the answers are correct, please accept an answer by clicking the checkmark near the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Shields are not in Minecraft 1.8.9. Shields are an upcoming feature in Minecraft 1.9, available in the snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make shields if you are playing on a version that is under 1.9

If you want to make one in the newer versions here is the recipe:

[image: Shield Recipie]